# Hive to HBase Integration using MapReduce instead of HBase Index?

Tags: hadoop, hive, hbase

I was under the impression that a hive table created ontop of an HBase table would forgoe MapReduce and utilize the HBase index entirely if you passed the rowkey to the where clause. However, my queries are using MapReduce and are very slow because of that.

I created one HBase table like so:

```
create '/app/SubscriptionBillingPlatform/Shishir','cf'
```

I created two external Hive tables to the HBase table, one for columns A,B,C, and the other for columns D,E,F:

[image]

I put 3 values into the table in the hbase shell, using 'abc' as the rowkey:

```
put '/app/SubscriptionBillingPlatform/Shishir','abc','cf:a','a'
put '/app/SubscriptionBillingPlatform/Shishir','abc','cf:b','b'
put '/app/SubscriptionBillingPlatform/Shishir','abc','cf:c','c'
```

Back in the hive shell, I then launch my query:

```
select * from shishir1 where key='abc';
```

[image]

I was expecting this to be almost as fast as querying the data from inside of HBase. However the Hive-HBase integration is using Map Reduce instead of the HBase index. Is there a way for me to get the Hive-HBase integration to forgo Mapreduce and utilize the HBase index entirely, or did I misunderstand that possibility?

Comment: So how do you infer that it is not using the HBase index while executing a MR job? If you want to optimize for three records, then go to the HBase shell and query it directly.

Comment: @ThomasJungblut Its taking 33 seconds to fetch a single row instead of 0.33 seconds. But I get your point and rephrased the question.

Comment: So your question boils down to: Why is Hive on HBase not a SQL engine on top of HBase rowkeys instead of MR on HBase?

Comment: @ThomasJungblut Note the "or did I misunderstand that possibility?" in the last paragraph.

Comment: We can't tell from the information that you gave us? Did the MR job really read 3 records or just 1? Will it matter? No, because it probably takes 33 seconds to start a MR job. You are looking for Apache Phoenix, not Hive.

Comment: @ThomasJungblut Would you be interested in answering the question instead of leaving a comment?